# How do you determine if a point is in front or behind a line segment using the Half Space test?

Tags: c++, opengl, line, point, glm-math

How do you determine if a point is in front of a line with the half space test?  I have tried the following. It works *most* of the time, but fails others.  Are there circumstances where it will not work?  For example, will it only work if all points are within certain quadrants?  If not, what am I incorrectly doing?

I have tried:

```
bool PointInFrontOfLine(Point testPoint, Point v1, Point v2)
{
    // Compute line normal
    double dx = v2.x - v1.x;
    double dy = v2.y - v1.y;
    double nx = -dy;
    double ny = dx;
    double length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
    nx /= length;
    ny /= length;
    glm::vec3 normal(nx, 0, ny);

    glm::vec3 vec(testPoint.x - v1.x, 0, testPoint.y - v1.y);

    double distance = glm::dot(vecTemp, normal);

    if (distance > 0)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: First you need a definition of what "in front" even means with a point and a line.

Comment: I should have stated that the "z" is "Y".  It's using DOOM coordinates.

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank so so much!  I was scratching my head all day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually do is to calculate the (left turned) normal vector to the line which is defined by the points `v1` and `v2`:

```
double dx = v2.x - v1.x;
double dy = v2.y - v1.y;
double nx = -dy;
double ny = dx;
double length = sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
nx /= length;
ny /= length;
glm::vec3 normal(nx, 0, ny);
```

This can be simplified:

```
glm::vec3 normal(v1.y - v2.y, 0, v2.x - v1.x);
normal = glm::normalize(normal);
```

Note, for the algorithm you can even skip the normalization, then you won't get the correct normal `distance`, but the sign of `distance` is still correct. This is sufficient in your case because you only check `distance > 0`:

```
glm::vec3 normal(v1.y - v2.y, 0, v2.x - v1.x);
```

Then you check if the angle between the `normal` vector and the vector from `v1` to `testPoint` is greater -90 degrees and less than +90 degrees:

```
glm::vec3 vec(testPoint.x - v1.x, 0, testPoint.y - v1.y);
double distance = glm::dot(vecTemp, normal);
```

This works, because in general The *dot* product of 2 vectors is equal the *cosine* of the angle between the 2 vectors multiplied by the magnitude (lenght) of both vectors. If the *cosine* of an angle is >= 0, the the angle is in range [-90°, 90°].

```
dot( A, B ) == length( A ) * length( B ) * cos( angle_A_B )
```

[image: A dot B]

But the algorithm only works, if `v2.x < v1.x` (In the following pictures the x-axis points from left to right and the y-axis points from bottom to top):

[image: v2.x < v1.x]

If the 2 points are swapped (`v2.x > v1.x`), then you'll get the opposite result:

[image: v2.x > v1.x]

Finally the code can be expressed somehow like this:

```
glm::dot(glm::vec2(testPoint.x-v1.x, testPoint.y-v1.y),
         glm::vec2(v1.y-v2.y, v2.x-v1.x)) * glm::sign(v1.x-v2.x) > 0
```

Of coures the result still depends on, what "in front of" means. In my assumptions it means, that the y coordinate of `testPoint` is less than the y coordinate of the intersection point of the line `v1` to `v2` with a parallel line to the y-axis through `testPoint`. This means it depends on your program logic and coordinate system if this algorithm always calculates "in front" or "in back".